# How do I get rid of gray boundaries for ArrayPlot in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I have the following plot.

```
lst={{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
ArrayPlot[lst, Mesh -> All, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3.], Gray, Opacity[0.1]]]
```

[image]

But it does not look as I expected, in which I want the grey boundaries/grids for the black squares to be overshadowed by the color of these black squares. Only show the gray boundaries/grids of the white squares.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. I've uploaded the output of your code to your question. From my understanding of your question re: "Only show the gray boundaries/grids of the white squares.", the output looks correct. There are no gray boundaries for the black squares. Did you have something else in mind or are you getting a different output? Or did you mean the outermost gray border?

Comment: @yoda: You can still see some shadows of the boundaries for the black squares, don't you?

Comment: I see it now. It wasn't apparent at first (probably because of my monitor), but changing it to a brighter color revealed it. This might not be straightforward, because `Grid`s are always layed _after_ the rest of the graphic is drawn. There is an undocumented option to work around this, but I can't seem to remember it right now. Let me search...

Comment: @yoda, I think you are looking for `Method->{"GridLinesInFront"->True}` sub-option for `GridLines`? I think regardless of which one (`Mesh` or `GridLines`) one uses, the solution will require use of a customized styling function for `MeshStyle` or `GridLinesStyle` that uses the value of the data in the neighboring cells to color segments of each mesh/grid line. Not straightforward indeed...

Comment: @kguler Yeah, I found that but that didn't work either. I have a custom solution below that's a reasonable workaround for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something that can be easily solved using built in options (AFAIK). You can define a custom function that plots the gridlines only at those rows and columns that you need and masks the others. Here is my solution:

```
gridArrayPlot[mat_?MatrixQ, options___] := Module[{dim = Dimensions@mat},
  Show[
    ArrayPlot[mat, Mesh -> ({Range[#1 - 1], Range[#2 - 1]} & @@ dim), options],
    ArrayPlot[mat, Mesh -> ({{0, #1}, {0, #2}} & @@ dim), 
       ColorRules -> {0 -> Directive[Opacity@0, White]}, 
       options /. Opacity[_] :> Opacity[1] /. (RGBColor[___] | GrayLevel[_]) :> White
    ]
  ]
]
```

The above solution first plots an `ArrayPlot`, drawing the mesh everywhere except at the outer boundaries and overlays a second `ArrayPlot` with the `White` cells set to be transparent, and draws `White` mesh lines on the outer boundary (to mask the bits sticking out from the previous plot).

You can call the above function as

```
gridArrayPlot[lst,MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3.],Gray,Opacity[0.1]]]
```

and the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about just ditching grid lines and mesh lines and using `Epilog` and `Line`?

```
ArrayPlot[lst, Mesh -> False, Frame -> False, 
 Epilog -> {GrayLevel[0.5], AbsoluteThickness[1], 
   Line@Table[{{2 + i, 8}, {2 + i, 1}}, {i, 0, 5}], 
   Line@Table[{{1, 2 + i}, {8, 2 + i}}, {i, 0, 5}]}]
```

[image]

This is obviously specific to this list of data but is straight forward to generalize to data where you have "x" unit black "perimeter" and "y" times "y" white square (i.e. a y+2x list of rows and columns).

```
gridArrayPlot[mat_?MatrixQ] := Module[{dim = First@Dimensions@mat, 
  white = Length@Cases[mat, {__, 0 .., __}], black, left, right, grid},

  black = (dim - white)/2;
  left = black + 1;
  right = dim - black;
  grid = white - 2;

  ArrayPlot[mat, Mesh -> False, Frame -> False, 
   Epilog -> {GrayLevel[0.5], AbsoluteThickness[1], 
     Line@Table[{{left + i, right}, {left + i, black}}, {i, 0, grid}],
      Line@Table[{{black, left + i}, {right, left + i}}, {i, 0, grid}]}]

  ]
```